# SQL Server can't see subst/virtual drive

Tags: sql-server, windows

I have been having trouble getting SQL Server to see subst/virtual drives at all.

For example:
I've used the subst command to create a F:/ drive that maps to C:/FDrive. The stored procedures use this F:/ drive to generate various files. If I programmatically change the folder location within the stored procs from F:/ to C:/FDrive they execute successfully.

Is there a fix or workaround available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `subst` just gives you a drive letter alias for your current session; it's not a server level thing.  This is not going to be possible using this command.  Use the real path instead.

Comment: Ended up partitioning my drive and creating an F drive. Thanks for the help!